# Conditions for boundedness of a inverse of invertible operator.

Tags: functional-analysis

I know about Banach Sapce. Recently, I have studied bounded linear operator.  I know example of a bounded operator whose inverse is not bounded. $T : \mathcal l^2 \longrightarrow \mathcal l^2$ defined by $T((x_n))=(x_1,\frac {x_2} {2}, \frac {x_3} {3},\cdots).$  Inverse of $T$ is not bounded.
My question is what is necessary condition for boundedness of invertible map. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces and if $T:X \to Y$ is an injective bounded linear operator, then $T^{-1}:T(X) \to X$ is bounded if $T(X)$ is a closed subspace of $Y$.

This is a consequence of  the open mapping theorem.

In your example above, the operator $T$ is injective, but $T(l^2)$ is not closed.

Comment: Yeah! Thank you!